# try catch in a try block - exception should call same function

Tags: c#, .net, exception

what if I would have something like this:

```
public static void DoSomething()
{
  try
  { 
    //some code
    try
    {
      //some other code
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      log.Error("At the end something is wrong: " + e);
      FunctionA(); //same function as in the first exception
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    log.Error("At the start something wrong: " + e);
    FunctionA();
  }
}
```

So I have one try catch in another. The exceptions should be different and I want to handel them with the logger different. But let say I would like to call the same function for both of the exceptions. I have to write `FunctionA()` 2 times. Is this alright? Or is there any other problem with this type of exception? Suggestions?

Comment: Why not just catch the specific exceptions instead of using `Exception e` in the catch statement?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Maybe you should show us your real code to get useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use single try block with multiple catch blocks; and also you can use finally statements to execute some code section whether there is an exception or not.

Using multiple try-catch blocks inside a function is generally not a good idea. Also, it is better to handle an exception at the placed it occured.

```
public static void DoSomething()
{
  try
  { 
    //some code
  }

  catch (ExceptionA e)
  {
    // exception is ExceptionA type
    log.Error("At the end something is wrong: " + e);
    FunctionA(); //same function as in the first exception    
  }
  catch (ExceptionB e)
  {
    // exception is ExceptionB type
    log.Error("At the start something wrong: " + e);
    FunctionA(); //same function as in the first exception    
  }
  finally
  {
        //you can do something here whether there is an exception or not
  }
}
```

Comment: @RB.: That's what is happening here.

Comment: Disagree with "it is better to handle an exception at the placed it occured." It depends...most of the time it is better to let the exception propagate up the call chain to a higher level exception handler.

Comment: @ShellShock I disagree with you. Even if you want to propagate the exception, it is better to handle it at the place it occured, you can propagate it once it is handled. If you do not handle the exception in the place it occured, then you will endup with a fault intolerant system. (ex. if the exception occurs in a db related section, will not have the chance the rollback the transaction).

Comment: @daryal "*it is better to handle it at the place it occurred*" - Yes it is, but only *if* you can. There are loads of scenarios where it is perfectly fine to let exceptions propagate straight up without handling them.

Comment: It all depends what you mean by handle. If "Handle" means make it like it never happended, or perform some specific remedial action then, this should be done locally, that is normally the only place this can be done. If it is some generic logging this should be at the top of your stack, so you can code it once.

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?

Comment: @daryal if you suppress the exception locally and don't fix the problem, how will the "db related section" know it needs to rollback. Why not let the exception rise, the "db related section" can handle the exception and perform the rollback.

Comment: I agree with @Jodrell and James. If by handling, you mean recover from the exception, then of course this should happen close to where the exception is raised. But in my experience there are few exceptions where recovery is possible or sensible. Practically every call you make into the .Net framework can raise an exception. Are you seriously suggesting you can catch all these where they are thrown, and recover from them?

Comment: @ShellShock, only the ones you expect.

Comment: @Jodrell Please read what I have suggested more carefully; I have suggested, if there is an exception related to DB, it shall be handled where it is risen; not the other way.

Comment: @ShellShock I would like to ask a simple question: If you were to write a huge business application; would you let the exceptions rise to the top layer before handling them?

Comment: @daryal, agreed, I have misinterpreted your statement and thus we broadly agree. It all comes down to the assertion, logging != handling.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to call a method in all exceptional cases. Then i would use a `Boolean` variable to store if all executed successfully. Then you can call `FunctionA` at the end accordingly:

```
public static void DoSomething()
{
    bool success = true;
    try
    {
        //some code
        try
        {
            //some other code
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            success = false;
            try
            {
                //some other code
            } catch (ExceptionA eA)
            {
                log.Error("At the end, something went wrong: " + eA);
            } catch (ExceptionB eB)
            {
                log.Error("At the end, something else went wrong: " + eB);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        success = false;
        log.Error("At the start something wrong: " + ex);
    }

    if(!success)
        FunctionA();
}
```

But if you instead want to call this method in any case, that means regardless whether an exception was raised, then you can use [`finally`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx). It is also useful if you want to clean resources.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your code into a reusble method e.g.

```
public void LogIfSomeException(Action action, string message)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (SomeException e)
    {
        log.Error(message + e);
        FunctionA();
    }
}
```

Which you could use like:

```
public static void DoSomething()       
{
    LogIfSomeException(() => {
       // start code
       LogIfSomeException(() => {
          // end code
       }, "At the end something is wrong");
    }, "At the start something is wrong");

}
```

Comment: A novel use of lambda expressions but I wouldn't like to see it in code I was maintaining.

Comment: @Jodrell It's not the prettiest block of code I will give you that, but sometimes complex problems requires complex code (in fairness, it's not *that* bad). OTOH sometimes when people see code becoming complex they begin to realise they have a design problem rather than a programming one.

Comment: agreed, that is the real problem here. I would nut suggest any of the solutions offered are elegant. The problem is the local logging.

Answer (score 0):

If you change `DoSomthing` to rethrow the exceptions like this,

```
public static void DoSomething()
{
  try
  { 
    //some code
    try
    {
      //some other code
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      log.Error("At the end something is wrong: " + e);
      throw;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    log.Error("At the start something wrong: " + e);
    throw;
  }
}
```

This makes some sense because logging the exception is not realy handling it, I'm dubious that `FunctionA` will do that either but ... . When you call `DoSomething`, you can catch either exception.

```
static void CallDoSomething()
{
    try
    {
       DoSomething();
    }
    catch
    {
       FunctionA();
    }
}
```

Or, if you really want to do it in the same function.

```
public static void DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        try
        { 

            // some code

            try
            {

                // some other code

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error("At the end something is wrong: " + e);
                throw;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error("At the start something wrong: " + e);
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) // I include the type in the hope it will be more derived.
    {
        FunctionA();
    }
}
```

Comment: So even if I get an exception at the end "At the end something is wrong" FunctionA() will be called?

Comment: Yes, the `throw` will rethrow the exception like you never caught it and it will rise to the next highest handler, in this case the outer try block.